# Can anyone recommend any good guides to ffmpeg outside of the official manual?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a hard time reading and understanding the official ffmpeg manual due to the lack of full command line examples per sections. Sections are completely hit and miss for me based on whether they provide these examples. For example I can understand the wiki ffmpeg pages on certain things cause they generally go into alot of detail and give alot of examples I can do on my own and just tinker with the values.

Are there any third party guides people can recommend that are very example heavy? As I said I need to see all the commands in a full command line example, or at least an explicit example and then just the separate callup parts in full....like -vf "filter1withfulldetails_onsetting_up_eachsetting". Many I find seem to be outdated or limited...both video and text, cause the commands just don't work right even when I copypaste....or the settings seem to have been changed cause on the ffmpeg guide they are different setting names entirely in some cases. I need to see the modern commands that work alongside the explanations to understand things better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this site by coincidence yesterday! It explains things in a bit more human readable format, perhaps.

https://amiaopensource.github.io/ffmprovisr/

Comment: This is really good. Do you know how up to date it is or if it's regularly updated? I'm reading it and some stuff like the codec defaults seems a bit off from what I'm getting, just curious how careful I need to be when viewing it.

Comment: *Do you know how up to date it is*  --> I don't think it is actively maintained. e.g. in [this](https://amiaopensource.github.io/ffmprovisr/index.html#cover_head), the value `max` was changed to `fill` over a year ago.

Comment: It's actively added to: there was an addition within the last 24 hrs. The contributors are from the archival community with a wide breadth of experience: some beginners, some more knowledgeable. They are appreciative of any pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

## Official FFmpeg Help Resources

- [FFmpeg Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/documentation.html)
- [FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/)
- [ffmpeg-user mailing list](https://ffmpeg.org/contact.html)
- #ffmpeg IRC channel on Freenode

## Unofficial Help Resources

- Stack Exchange sites: [video.se], [su], [so] - Might be easiest for you to just search/ask here.
- [Zeranoe Forum](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/)
- [r/ffmpeg](https://www.reddit.com/r/ffmpeg/)
- [ffmpeg.tv](http://ffmpeg.tv/) - FFmpeg Basics Book. I haven't looked at it. A few users told me they liked it, but it is not free ($9.50 USD) and I'm not sure if it is kept up to date.

Comment: Already had a look through those unfortunately.

Comment: The ffmpeg manual doesn't do much holistic explanation. Rather the aim is to be comprehensive, although it falls short of that goal and which I aim to rectify over the next year. Part of the problem is that the docs are a broth formed by too many cooks. Consistency of form and style hasn't been set.

Comment: I do have plans for a holistic overview but I expect that to take at least a couple of months.

Comment: Even if there can just be specific examples added for the remaining filters or things that don't have them, that helps make things many times more readable for me anyways.